# Ruby how to extend method to accept new parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puppet, theforeman

I hope someone can help me with this.

I have this method in ruby:

```
def puppetrun_oneClass!
   ProxyAPI::Puppet.new({:url => puppet_proxy.url}).runSingle fqdn
end
```

which I then call within this other method:

```
def update_multiple_puppetrun_oneClass_deploy
   if @hosts.map(&:puppetrun_oneClass!).uniq == [true]
      notice "Successfully executed, check reports and/or log files for more details"
   else
      error "Some or all hosts execution failed, Please check log files for more information"
   end
end
```

where *@hosts* is an array of hostnames.

Now, I would like to extend  **puppetrun_oneClass!** to accept the *@myDeploy* parameter, where *@myDeploy* parameter is a variable containing a string.

How could I do that?? and how should I then call the modified method?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add it as an argument, however this means you need to declare a long-form block to your `map` loop.

New method:

```
def puppetrun_oneClass!(deploy)
  # ... Code using `deploy` variable
end
```

New call:

```
@hosts.map { |h| host.puppetrun_oneClass!(@myDeploy) }.uniq
```

Note that `uniq` is a pretty heavy handed approach here if you just want to see if any of them failed. You might want to try `find` which would stop at the first one that fails rather than blindly executing them all:

```
!@hosts.find { |h| !host.puppetrun_oneClass!(@myDeploy) }
```

This will ensure that none of them returned a false condition. If you want to run them all and look for errors, you might try:

```
 failures = @hosts.reject { |h| host.puppetrun_oneClass!(@myDeploy) }

 if (failures.empty?)
   # Worked
 else
   # Had problems, failures contains list of failed `@hosts`
 end
```

The first part returns an array of any `@hosts` entries that failed. It might be useful to capture this list and use it to produce a more robust error message, perhaps describing those that didn't work.